# Back up RDS snapshots to S3 automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have RDS which autobackup period is 7 days.

And I have found I can backup the RDS's snapshot to S3 manually.

However I want to make back up RDS snapshot sautomatically to S3.

How can I do this , I should make event bridge?

Comment: Yes, even bridge scheduled rule + lambda.

Comment: RDS snapshots are already stored in S3.  Why do you want to redundantly store a snapshot when it is already stored until you delete it?

Comment: ＠Marcin Thank you , event rule + lambda. Nice hint, I will google around further.

Comment: @gview already stored means , it automatically stored in ? however how can I set the target S3 to RDS setting??

Comment: An Amazon RDS Snapshot can be [exported to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html). What will you be doing with the exports in Amazon S3? Or is it only as a "backup of the snapshot"?

Comment: @John Rotenstein
 Yes I have exported one snapshots with `Export to Amazon S3` function. however I want to do this automatically every day. What I want to do is just backup the snapshots

Comment: You could do it using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), as a Windows Scheduled Event or a Linux cron job. However, I would question the need for it, since Amazon RDS Snapshots are stored in the Amazon S3 infrastructure and are therefore very resilient (copied between multiple data centers). There should be no need to "backup a backup".

Comment: @John Rotenstein, thank you for your explanation. `Amazon RDS Snapshots are stored in the Amazon S3 infrastructure` I still have question. S3 is perpetual storage, but RDS backup lasts only 35 days at longest. Is there any good method to back to two month ago or etc?

Comment: There are two types of Amazon RDS Snaphots -- Automatic DB snapshots (maximum retention 35 days) and Manual DB snapshots that remain until you delete them. You can use [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/aws-backup.html) to create a Manual snapshot at regular intervals. This way, there will be backups that you could restore from previous time periods.

Answer (score 2):

The first stop for an answer about an AWS service is normally the AWS documentation.
Since sometimes finding the right section in the sea of info could be a bit overwhelming, please find below references that should answer your question.
There are 3 ways you could  export an RDS snapshot to S3:

1. Using the management console
2. the AWS CLI
3. RDS APIs

The [Exporting DB snapshot data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html) AWS document explains each process in detail.
As described in previous comments, you could for instance **using a lambda to trigger the RDS APIs**.
Even more interesting, AWS provide a GitHub repository with the code to automate the export. Please find the [code here](https://github.com/aws-samples/rds-snapshot-export-to-s3-pipeline).

As mentioned in the document, please note that:

> Exporting RDS snapshots can take a while depending on your database type and size. The export task first restores and scales the entire database before extracting the data to Amazon S3. The task's progress during this phase displays as Starting. When the task switches to exporting data to S3, progress displays as In progress. The time it takes for the export to complete depends on the data stored in the database. For example, tables with well-distributed numeric primary key or index columns export the fastest. Tables that don't contain a column suitable for partitioning and tables with only one index on a string-based column take longer. This longer export time occurs because the export uses a slower single-threaded process.